# Best Practice: Apache File Upload

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, file-transfer, upload

I am looking for a soultion for trusted users to upload pdf files via html forms (with maybe php involved). This is quite a standard ubuntu linux server with apache 2.x and php 5.

I am wonderiung what are the benefits of the apache file upload module. There were no updates for some time, is it actively maintained? What are the advantages over traditional php upload with apache 2 without this module?

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload

I remember traditional php file upload is difficult with some pitfalls, will the apache file upload module improve the situation?

The solution I am looking for will be part of an existing website and be integrated into the admin web frontend. Things I am *not* considering are webdav, ssh, ftp, ftps, ftp over ssh. Should work with a browser and without installing special client software, so I am asking about a browser based upload without special client side requirements. I can request a modern browser like firefox >= 3.5 or modern webkit broser like chrome or safari from the users.

Comment: I see this as a server question, it touches mainly issues like file transfer, quotas, permissions and such.

Comment: i have planned to test out free open source project fffex : http://freshmeat.net/projects/fffex
Is it part of an existing web site of do you search a dedicated solution for that ?

Comment: Will be part of existing site, I added an "Edit" to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to use PHP. The software you mentioned is Java. So I don't think it is what you want.

Maybe have a look here:
http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/upload-systems/

Beware: commercial license also listed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing Apache httpd (Web Server) with other Apache Group projects. Apache Group hosts the "Commons" project which a large collection of Java libraries for use in your own Java applications. In this case commons-fileupload is (used to be...) a somewhat popular library for handling file uploads in Java Servlets, but it has nothing to do with the Apache webserver (except that you could build a Java app/servelet using it, that ran inside say Apache Tomcat, that talked to an Apache httpd webserver).

I think you're better off using PHP's built-in file upload handling if you're going to write your own code. It's simple and it works. See [the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).